# HyperLedger Fabric and Docker Swarm: Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL

Tags: docker, ssl, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, docker-swarm

We are trying to establish a **grpcs** (TLS) connection between a docker container running **API server** (based on Node.js) and another docker container running **peer0** from Fabric network.
All containers are orchestated by **docker swarm**, and both containers happen to be running on the same Linux host.

The error log thrown by API container is the following:

> 2021-01-07T18:27:38.110Z - error: [Remote.js]: Error: Failed to
> connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://10.0.1.2:9051 Query has
> completed, checking results error from query =  { Error: Failed to
> connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://10.0.1.2:9051
> at checkState (/usr/src/app/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:833:16) connectFailed:
> true } sampleEvent ERROR : Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connect Failed E0107
> 18:27:53.602719124      16 ssl_transport_security.cc:1229] Handshake
> failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:14090086:SSL
> routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed.

And the error log thrown from peer0 is:

> 2021-01-07 18:50:22.224 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 043 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=PeerServer remoteaddress=10.0.1.4:46212

**IP addresses layout**

- IP address for API container is 10.0.1.94
- IP address for peer0 container is 10.0.1.3
- virtual IP address for docker service peer0 is 10.0.1.2
- IP address for docker swarm load balancer endpoint is 10.0.1.4

Any suggestion of where to further troubleshoot? At this point is not clear if the problem is with the docker swarm internal networking, or an issue with ssl certificates in either side of the network.

## UPDATE Feb 2 2021

The original TLS handshake error was fixed by upgrading the javascript used in NodeSDK. Among other things we started using the `addToWallet.js` script contained in the *commercial-paper* example

After being able to stablish TLS succesfully between Node.js API and peer0, we get a new `access denied` error when making a simple query to `chaincode_example02`

Facts:

1. We are running the query with 2 Admin users
2. One Admin is first-network original **Admin@org1.example.com**, with credentials generated by `cryptogen` tool
3. The other Admin is **Admin@buyer.dlt.com** whose credentials were created with openssl and a self signed in-company CA
4. From CLI, both Admin are good and are allowed to run peer commands interchangeably
5. From Node.js app, only **Admin@org1.example.com** is allowed to run queries. The message printed to console.log is:

```
Transaction has been evaluated, result is: 100
```

6. When running queries with **Admin@buyer.dlt.com** we get the following error logs:

Error logs from **peer0@buyer.dlt.com**

```
2021-02-02T04:08:45.291086617Z ^[[36m2021-02-02 04:08:45.290 UTC [protoutils] checkSignatureFromCreator -> DEBU 6e637^[[0m creator is &{BuyerMSP 8b7cc2ee996be4f7e5dbb1a4f64db67afd2ff8a2f41276c9bd7f33a2447dd9df}
2021-02-02T04:08:45.291094817Z ^[[36m2021-02-02 04:08:45.290 UTC [protoutils] checkSignatureFromCreator -> DEBU 6e638^[[0m creator is valid
2021-02-02T04:08:45.291100418Z ^[[36m2021-02-02 04:08:45.290 UTC [msp.identity] 2021-02-02T04:08:45.303821799Z ^[[33m2021-02-02 04:08:45.303 UTC [protoutils] ValidateProposalMessage -> WARN 6e63b^[[0m channel [mychannel]: creator's signature over the proposal is not valid: The signature is invalid
2021-02-02T04:08:45.303891604Z ^[[36m2021-02-02 04:08:45.303 UTC [endorser] func1 -> DEBU 6e63c^[[0m Exit: request from 10.0.1.84:52696
2021-02-02T04:08:45.303902005Z ^[[34m2021-02-02 04:08:45.303 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 6e63d^[[0m unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.peer_address=10.0.1.84:52696 error="access denied: channel [mychannel] creator org [BuyerMSP]" grpc.code=Unknown grpc.call_duration=13.783655ms
```

Error log on console.log from script query.js:

```
2021-02-02T04:08:45.305Z - error: [Channel.js]: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: access denied: channel [mychannel] creator org [BuyerMSP]
2021-02-02T04:08:45.307Z - error: [Network]: _initializeInternalChannel: Unable to initialize channel. Attempted to contact 1 Peers. Last error was Error: 2 UNKNOWN: access denied: channel [mychannel] creator org [BuyerMSP]
Failed to evaluate transaction: Error: Unable to initialize channel. Attempted to contact 1 Peers. Last error was Error: 2 UNKNOWN: access denied: channel [mychannel] creator org [BuyerMSP]
```

Comment: Are you trying to access the peer from the API server via hostname or IP address?
What are the SANs in the peer's TLS certificate?

Comment: @GariSingh I have tried accessing peer both ways. with IP address of via hostname. The SAN in peer TLS certificate matches the hostname. Couple of more facts:

1) Peer is pingable from the API container via its SAN

2) The API container is using the Admin credentials to connect. When using the same Admin credentials from CLI container, it works like a charm

3) In order to discard a internal docker swarm TLS networking issue, I have just spinned up a standalone peer container with the same (bad) results. At least we know it is not docker swarm creating noise.

Comment: Any ideas why peer is throwing error EOF? We are passing credentials to the API which it uses to stablish TLS connection towards peer. Perhaps peer is receiving a malformed message from the API?

Comment: Is the Node.js using the right CA certificate (the one which issued the TLS cert for the peer)?

Comment: EOF typically means the client terminated the connection

Comment: The CA.crt we are passing to the Node.js APP is the same CA.crt that issued the TLS certificate for the peer (server.crt).
Will have a check on the EOF and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: I did not notice before that the EOF error was from the Docker Swarm LB address, so this might be a red herring in terms of debugging the client issue.  But the error in the client is clear:  it cannot verify the TLS certificate from the peer.  You can disable verification in the client and see if it works then.   But I still suspect that there is a mismatch between SAN/hostname or with the CA cert you have configured.

Comment: So we finally found something: the (Admin) user private key under MSP folder structure is  EC encoded (i.e. starts with **BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY**)
But the private key stored in the wallet that is used by client app SDK, (the wallet is generated by _FileSystemWallet_ library) converts the key to PKCS#8 (i.e. start with **BEGIN PRIVATE KEY**).
I guess that is the reason why we got the error log on peer?:
`creator's signature over the proposal is not valid: The signature is invalid`

Comment: So the EC encoded private key is valid to be used from the CLI container, but must be converted to PKCS#8 when stored in a filesystem wallet?

Comment: Is there a different error now?  The error in the comment above does not seem related to the original TLS error?

Comment: You are right Gari. We fixed the TLS error by upgrading the fabric SDK library, then we got the new error related to the private key being invalid

Comment: Can you post more details from the "signature invalid" logs?

Comment: We get ``The signature is invalid`` when querying the ledger with a user whose private key is PEM encoded. On the other hand, when issuing the same query to the ledger with the Admin@org1.example.com credentials, it works ok.
The funny thing is that both users are good to be used from the CLI interface.
The only difference is that our own user private key is formated as *BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY* , and the Admin@org1.example.com private key is formated as *BEGIN PRIVATE KEY*

Comment: See below the error logs from peer0:

```2021-01-28T16:14:12.911527470Z ^[[33m2021-01-28 16:14:12.911 UTC [protoutils] ValidateProposalMessage -> WARN 5db7c^[[0m channel [mychannel]: creator's signature over the proposal is not valid: The signature is invalid
2021-01-28T16:14:12.911547372Z ^[[36m2021-01-28 16:14:12.911 UTC [endorser] func1 -> DEBU 5db7d^[[0m Exit: request from 10.0.1.84:36832```

Comment: Which query are you running?  And are you using the exact same private/public key pair?  Depending on how you have things set up, the admin public key must explicitly match they public cert in the MSP folder (for the channel or for the local MSP of the peer depending on what you are invoking).

Comment: I am using the `query.js` from commercial_paper example, to query the value of `var a` in `example_chaincode02`.
Just to ensure we are on the same page: **0)** we are running the query with 2 different Admin users. 
**1)** One Admin is Admin@org1.example.com, whose credentials were generated by `cryptogen`
**2)** Other Admin is Admin@buyer.dlt.com , whose credentials were generated by `openssl` and a local CA.
**3)** Both users are allowed to run query from CLI container (passing the appropiated keys and certs)
**4)** Only Admin@org1.example.com is allowed to run query from **Node SDK**.

Comment: **5)** When running the query with **Admin@buyer.dlt.com** I get `The signature is invalid`. **6)** As mentioned above, the **`/commercial-paper/addToWallet.js`** scripts generates SDK credentials for **Admin@buyer.dlt.com** , and converts the existing private key format from EC to PK8. Thus, private key stored in the wallet (i.e. starts with *BEGIN PRIVATE KEY*) does not match original private key stored in the MSP folder (i.e. start with *BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY*)

Comment: **Question**: I suppose we must ensure private key format in MSP folder is PK8, in order to match the key that will be used by the wallet app within the Node SDK?

Comment: @GariSingh I generated new credentials for our Admin@buyer.dlt.com to ensure the private key has the same formatting as Admin@org1.example.com, but we still get the **access denied** error. 
Please check the UPDATE on the main post, I have added logs from peer as well as console.log errors... Any ideas where to look at?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, this issue turned out to be two issues, in a 'russian doll like' style.

**1. First issue: `TLS Handshake error`**
This was fixed by upgrading the SDK library to the latest release

**2. Second issue: Node SDK query triggers error "`The signature is invalid`".**
The reason turned out to be that the CLI (written on Go) is using the Go crypto support which allows it to generate a signature from a hash without any knowledge of the curve used for the key. Instead, the SDK libraries used by the Node implementation require a specific curve to be specified by the code generating the signature, separately from the private key itself.
Bottom line, private keys used within Node SDK should be P-256.
As an alternative, as suggested by hyperledger dev team:

> If you really must use a curve other than P-256 then you might be able
> to use one of the following approaches:
>
> -Use the off-line signing approach included in the documentation but specify an alternative curve instead of 'p256'. The supported curves
> for the elliptic package documented here:
> https://github.com/indutny/elliptic
>
> -Set your own CryptoSuite implementation on the Client that underpins the Gateway object, with your own CryptoSuite.sign() implementation:
> https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-2.2/CryptoSuite.html#sign